# Como plotar mapa com nome dos lugares - ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geolocalização

Baixei os dados e plotei um mapa com a densidade demográfica das cidades da Região Metropolitana de São Paulo. Mas fica difícil identificar as cidades.

```
rmsp <- readOGR("rmsp", "MunRM07", stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "latin1")

rmsp_data <- rmsp@data
rmsp_poligonos <- rmsp@polygons
rmsp_projecao <- rmsp@proj4string

url_munic_15 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leobarone/FLS6397/master/data/planejamento_munic_2015.csv"
munic_15 <- read.table(url_munic_15, header = T, sep = ";") %>%
   rename(COD_IBGE = A1, ano_pd = A18) %>%
   select(COD_IBGE, ano_pd) %>%
   mutate(ano_pd = as.numeric(as.character(ano_pd)))

rmsp@data <- rmsp@data %>% 
   mutate(ID = as.numeric(ID), COD_IBGE = as.numeric(COD_IBGE),
          DENS_DEMO = as.numeric(DENS_DEMO)) %>%
   left_join(munic_15, by = "COD_IBGE")

 rmsp_df <- fortify(rmsp)

rmsp_df$id <- as.numeric(rmsp_df$id)
   rmsp@data$id <- 0:(nrow(rmsp@data)-1)
   rmsp_df <- left_join(rmsp_df, rmsp@data, by = "id")

ggplot(data = rmsp_df, 
       aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = DENS_DEMO)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  coord_map()
```

Como identificar os lugares para termos noção das posições no mapa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se colocarmos a função *label* dentro de **aes()** antes de tratarmos os dados, para cada linha no df ele plotará um nome. Ficaremos com milhares de repetições se sobrepondo.

A solução que encontrei foi criar um objeto agrupando os nomes e uma posição média das latitudes e longitudes para localizar onde o nome irá ser plotado. Também achei necessário filtrar as cidades por tamanho, pois cidades menores e menos conhecidas sobrepunham cidades maiores e mais conhecidas, o que dificulta localização.

```
nome_cidade <- rmsp_df %>% # Cria o objeto 
   filter(as.numeric(AREA_KM2) > 100) %>% # Filtra cidades com areas maiores de 100km2
   group_by(NOME) %>% # Agrupa para nomes únicos evitando repetição e sobreposição 
   summarise(long = mean(long), lat = mean(lat)) # Tira a média das coordenadas
```

Agora plotaremos o mapa inserindo a linha *geom_text* com os parâmetros baseados no objeto criado acima. Ela é quem colocará os nomes.

```
ggplot(data = rmsp_df, 
       aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
   geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = DENS_DEMO)) +
   geom_text(aes(label = NOME), check_overlap = T, data = nome_cidade, color = "white", size = 3, hjust = 0.5) +
   coord_map()
```

Importante notar o *check_overlap = T* se não quiser nomes se sobrepondo no mapa.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é usar as centróides para plotar os nomes. Como não postou seu shapefile, estou usando um que já possuo de exemplo e simulando alguns dados aleatórios:

```
shape <- rgdal::readOGR('~/Shapefiles/', 'BRregioes')

> shape@data
  CD_GEOREG    NM_REGIAO
0         1        Norte
1         5 Centro-Oeste
2         2     Nordeste
3         3      Sudeste
4         4          Sul

dados <- data.frame(
  Regiao = shape@data$NM_REGIAO,
  variavel = rnorm(5, 10) )
```

Usando `geom_map` não é preciso mesclar os dados das regiões com o shapefile, basta uma coluna de identificação com os mesmos nomes. Para os rótulos, calcule as centróides e use essa informação junto com o data.frame com os dados:

```
centroides <- as.data.frame(rgeos::gCentroid(shape, byid = TRUE))
centroides$Regiao <- shape@data$NM_REGIAO

shape.f <- fortify(shape, region = 'NM_REGIAO')

ggplot(merge(dados, centroides)) +
  geom_map(map = shape.f, aes(map_id = Regiao, fill = variavel)) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = Regiao), color = 'white') +
  expand_limits(x = shape.f$long, y = shape.f$lat) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Pode usar `geom_label` no lugar de `geom_text` se quiser mais destaque para os nomes.